# How to get out of the loop after reading inputStream with buffered reader

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

Hi I'm learning socket programming through an assignment, I'm trying to read my json string using buffered reader but somehow ((line = br.readLine()) != null) in my while loop only returns true which i think keeps me in the loop even after reading

how can i solve

```
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
```

Comment: The loop will terminate when the condition becomes false, which is at end of stream, for example, end of file, or if a socket, when the peer closes the connection, or shuts it down for output.

Comment: @user207421 thanks i just had to call pw.close() :)